# On the definition of small categories in SGA4

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, foundations

We assume ZFC+U.
A *category* is an ordered pair $(\operatorname{Ob} \mathcal{C},\operatorname{Mor} \mathcal{C},\operatorname{dom},\operatorname{codom},e,∘)$ of sets (not classes) and maps satifying some conditions.

Let $\mathbb{U}$ be a Grothendieck universe.
An element of $\mathbb{U}$ is called a *$\mathbb{U}$-set*.
A set is called *$\mathbb{U}$-small* if it is isomorphic to a $\mathbb{U}$-set.
In the following, we suppose that $\mathbb{N} \in \mathbb{U}$.

In SGA4, a category $\mathcal{C}$ is called *$\mathbb{U}$-small*
if $(\operatorname{Ob} \mathcal{C},\operatorname{Mor} \mathcal{C},\operatorname{dom},\operatorname{codom},e,∘)$ is $\mathbb{U}$-small
as a set (if my understanding is correct).
However, I don't see this definition working well.
For any set $a$ and $b$,
an ordered pair $(a,b)$ is always $\mathbb{U}$-small
since $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\} \}$ is a set consisting of exactly two elements,
which is isomophic to $2:=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\} \in \mathbb{U}$.
Thus, $\mathbb{U}$-smallness imposes nothing on categories.
In particular, it is not equivalent to $\operatorname{Ob} \mathcal{C}$ and $\operatorname{Mor} \mathcal{C}$ are $\mathbb{U}$-small.

I think I am mistaken somewhere, where is it?

Comment: Could you refer specifically to where this definition occurs?

Comment: In the [new edition of SGA 4](http://www.normalesup.org/~forgogozo/SGA4/tomes/SGA4.pdf), there is an editor's footnote on p. 2: "A category is viewed as a set of arrows".

Comment: It has been a long time since I looked at SGA 4 but do they actually define smallness as you say...? My impression was that they define a notion that is _not_ bijection-invariant.

Comment: @Zhen Lin In page 2 of SGA 4 (see abx's link above), he says 'On dit qu’un ensemble est U-petit (ou, quand aucune confusion n’en résulte, petit) s’il est isomorphe à un élément de U.'

Comment: @abx If that were the case, we would have to treat a category as an ordered pair of a set of morohisms, compositions, and so on. In that case, we end up with the same problem.

Comment: @LSpice My source is exactly the part pointed out by abx.

Comment: In my view this is a completely artificial problem. We all know very well what is a small category, don't we?

Comment: @abx What you are saying is completely correct. We can interpret all claims in the proper sense. However, I am afraid that the above assertion about the smallness of the pair may produces errors in various places. So I would like to know if I am wrong in the above discussion.

Comment: You are not wrong in the narrow sense but at the same time I think it is clear to you what the authors actually meant, so you are wrong to make a fuss of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re correct: read literally, those definitions are mismatched, for the reasons you give.  The solution is to fix the definition of “$U$-small category” to say that “$\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}\newcommand{\mor}{\mathrm{mor}}\mor(\C)$ is $\newcommand{\ob}{\mathrm{ob}}U$-small” — this is what the authors of SGA4 clearly intended (as clarified in the footnote on p2 of [this modern edition](http://www.normalesup.org/%7Eforgogozo/SGA4/tomes/SGA4.pdf), pointed out [by @abx in comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439306/on-the-definition-of-small-categories-in-sga4#comment1133094_439306)), but expressed in a way that doesn’t depend on the precise encoding of the definition of categories or of ordered pairs.

There are two general points here:

- Outside of explicit investigations of set-theoretically foundational issues (and usually even within such contexts), *nothing* should ever depend on the specific set-theoretic implementation of ordered pairs.  Anything that seems to depend on it can very safely be assumed to be a misunderstanding, an abuse of notation, or a mismatch of definitions.
- More generally, mathematics is usually written in “implementation-independent” ways as far as possible.  Of course, there are often lapses from this in practice, and that sometimes leads to mismatches, as here.  When such mismatches happen, the right fix is to rewrite the later definitions in more implementation-independent ways, *not* to tweak the implementation of the earlier definitions so that the implementation-dependent later definitions work.  In ordinary human-practiced mathematics, this usually isn’t a problem, because it’s clear what people meant.  But in computer-formalised mathematics (and programming more generally), this is a serious concern: if you go back and change the implementation of the earlier definition to make one later definition work, then that may break *anything else* that was written in an implementation-specific way.  Implementation-dependent definitions are inherently fragile — so fix *them*, don’t take them as god-given and twist other things around to try to work with them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was very convincing from a philosophical point of view.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a satisfactory solution to the above problem in [this MO answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2383564/541550) 
and would like to describe it here.

The *ordered pair* of sets $x$ and $y$ is a set $(x,y)$ which satisfies
$$(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x_1=x_2 \quad \text{and} \quad y_1=y_2.$$
The standard way to construct such sets is *Kuratowski ordered pairs*,
which is used in my question above:
$$\langle x,y \rangle:= \{ \{x\}, \{x,y\} \}.$$
However, there is another way to construct ordered pairs,
which is described in the MO answer above:
$$\lbrack x,y \rbrack:= x\times\{0\} \cup y\times\{1\}.$$
It is clear that $\lbrack x,y \rbrack$ also satisfies the condition of ordered pairs.
This ordered pair is not standard but solve my question.
We can easily see that $\lbrack x,y \rbrack$ is $\mathbb{U}$-small
if and only if both $x$ and $y$ are $\mathbb{U}$-small.
Thus, if we define a category as an ordered pair
$\lbrack \operatorname{Ob} \mathcal{C},\operatorname{Mor} \mathcal{C},\operatorname{dom},\operatorname{codom},e,\circ \rbrack$ satisfying some conditions,
then it is $\mathbb{U}$-small if and only if
both $\operatorname{Ob} \mathcal{C}$ and $\operatorname{Mor} \mathcal{C}$ are $\mathbb{U}$-small as desired.

As suggested in the MO answer above,
a suitable construction of ordered pair for category theory might be $\lbrack x,y \rbrack$.

Comment: This is ingenious, but it’s not the right way to approach fixing this problem; I explain why in [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/440169/2273).